# References on best practices for registration keys/access codes format

Tags: e-commerce, usability, registration

I am developing an online site to which access will be sold at college bookstores.  Students will purchase a card at the bookstore with an access code that they may then use to register online at our site.

I want to make the code as user friendly as possible.  I personally hate registering for a product and having to type in a registration key 5 times because it's ambiguous.

Can anyone point me to resources describing best practices for designing the format of the code itself?  Obvious things spring to mind-- don't use zeroes or the letter O, don't make it case sensitive, include some kind of checksum.  I don't want to be creative here, I need a recipe for what must be a problem solved many times.

Answer (score 1):

Joel Spolsky had some good insights to solving this problem in one of the recent StackOverflow podcasts.  I believe the episode was #49, you should download podcasts or checkout the transcripts at **https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4**

Dealing with 0 (number) and O (letter) mixed in a key is really annoying as some fonts make it hard to distinguish the two.

Other usability concepts such as groups of three being easier to deal with and remember then a single number are good to be aware of.  For example, 345-829-817-432 instead of 345829817432.

By the way, **345-829-817-432** gives you 12^10 permutations, and even the smaller number **345-829-817** gives you 9^10 permutations which may give you enough strength depending on your situation.

tschüss,

bn

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how much security you need.  A few ideas come to mind.

If you want something really simple you could generate simulated credit card numbers; students are adept at using these four-digit combinations, and they can be checked with a Luhn algorithm.

If you want something a little stronger you could generate a GUID, and use that as the code.

If your website can send emails you can ask the student for their email address, and send them a challenge/response email.  Then you don't need codes at all.  Their email address is the code.

Comment: thanks - good tips.  Security is one part of it, but I'm mostly concerned about ease-of-use.  They are prepaying for access to the system.  I want them to take the code and have it be easy to get started.  I don't want them to get hung up on mistaking zero for letter oh, for example.